# A function optimization problem with constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraint-programming

Let a, b, c be three real number constants satisfying $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq 1$. Define the function $f(x, y, z) = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2(1+z)}$ under the constraints $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 \leq \mu^2$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$. Now I want to calculate the minimal value of $f(x,y,z)$. My mathod is construct the following Laganrange:

$L(x, y, z, \lambda) = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2(1+z)} + \lambda\left((x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 - \mu^2\right)$

Because the point $(x,y,z)$ is in the unit sphere, so I abandoned the constraint term that the point lies inside the unit sphere in the Lagrange function. After partial derivatives with respect to $x,y,z,\lambda$ and set them to zero to find critical points:

$L_x=\frac{x}{1+z}+2\lambda (x-a)=0$

$L_y=\frac{y}{1+z}+2\lambda (y-b)=0$

$L_z=-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2(1+z)^2}+2\lambda (z-c)=0$

$L_\lambda=(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 - \mu^2=0$.

The question is how to solve the equations above?

Comment: You need to include the constraint $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 -1 \le 0$ in the Lagrange function. $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 \le 1$ and $(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2 +(z-c)^2 \le \mu^2$ does not imply that $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \le 1$.

Comment: Since the point (x,y,z) is in the unit sphere, so I could calculate Lagrange function without the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1$ to find the optimal value. Then, by optimizing and solving for the corresponding values of (x, y, z), it can be determined whether the point is inside the unit sphere.

Comment: And what if the optimal solution in your approach is not inside the unit sphere?

Comment: I will abandon the optimal solution which is not inside the unit sphere. The difficulty with this problem lies in finding the zeros of the Lagrange equations.